# User feedback remains when changing state in Sketchflow

Tags: sketchflow, expression-sketchflow

Wanting to check if I missed a setting somewhere, or if I'm just using the product in an unintended fashion.

I've created a prototype based on an existing site, and am using states to mimic functionality, along with tabcontrols and the like.  When the end-user is marking up the page, and then changes tabs, or clicks a button to change states (but stay on the same 'screen'), the drawings from the end-user remain in the same spot.  The issue is that if the user highlighted or crossed something out, it interferes with the new state.

Is this intended, an undocumented feature, or am I just expecting a little too much?  This may be a dealbreaker for us using this tool in our organization if we can't either resolve or have a reasonable workaround.  I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: I think you have the wrong forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I believe feedback is stored at the 'screen' level not the 'state' level**

I suppose you have 3 choices:

1. Instruct your users to list the steps they did before they add their feedback
2. Change your states to different screens instead (they can still look like the same screen for the end user, but in your application they will be different screens)
3. Have your user submit screen shots instead of just .feedback files

The second option will allow you to organize your feedback better.

In short I think you're expecting more than they offer ;)

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the impression that you're right :)  Option 2 is the way I think we're going to have to take it.  At least I know I'm not crazy now.  Thanks much.